# Open ANY EXISTING LINK on system browser

Tags: android, cordova

I have an application thath retrieves json from a REST API with some HTML content I show on a HTMl widget, and I need all this links retrieved to be opened outside application on system browser, mainly due to inside app is very very slow to open, and my app is locked to portrait, and links should be viewed on landscape.

My app retrieve data from a REST API, and show the HTML content, but I don't have control about links of this HTML retrieved, in form of

In some windows, I have some buttons using window.open with _system parameter and it's working like a charm, but the solution we need, is a way to specify all links should be opened outside the app, because we haven't control about links of HTML content retrieved.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, isn't this the default Android behavior?  I was under the impression that links will open in the system-default browser (not your app) unless you explicitly tell you app to handle that kind of activity.

Comment: No. Seems by default links open in the same webview of the phonegap application. A little more investigation, links failing was PDF links. I asked on IRC phonegap channel, and seems like PDF links can't be managed under Android. I mean, it's suppose should work under iOS, but under Android behaviour is not the same, and I need to to do a window.open(link, "_system") to give the system browser the responsability to open this file.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to a similar question is even more appropriate here, so I will repeat it:
The idea is to intercept clicks and act on any link that begins with 'http'.

```
window.onclick = clickEvent;

function clickEvent(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement
    if ( t.name || t.href ){
       if( typeof t.href == "string" && t.href.substr(0,4) == 'http' ){
           if( t.attributes.href.value !== "#" ){
               window.open(t.href, '_system', 'location=yes');
           }
           return false; // no further action for this click
       }
    }
    return true; // process click as normal
}
```

I'm hoping that Cordova will settle down a bit and older techniques ( target="_system" ) will suffice in which case you might only need to use `<base target="_system">` to set the default. Pre-3.0 non-whitelisted links were fine. Now the above is all that works for me.